# Would you please forward a message?

Tags: support

I would very much like to send a private e-mail to your site's subscriber who goes by the name of "johnwbyrd".  I imagine you rightfully don't give out e-mail addresses, but would you please notify "johnwbyrd" that I'd like to send him an e-mail message and tell him that my private e-mail address is R.Lyons@ieee.org?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello "Normal Human".  Thanks for your advice, I'll remember it. I appreciate your trouble.  By the way, are you really "normal"?

Answer (score 2):

Rick, as *Normal Human* says in the comment, I (and the other mods) generally can't do that. What *Human* suggests is normally your best bet.

However, a simple Google search for "johnwbyrd" suggests that [this github user](https://github.com/johnwbyrd)  and [this DSP.SE user](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/13700/johnwbyrd?tab=profile) are the same person. They use the same profile pictures and the same user name, anyhow.

The github link points [to this blog page](http://www.giganticsoftware.com/author/john-byrd/) which may also help.

Comment: Hello Dr. K.  Thanks for your help.  I searched the web for "johnwbyrd signal" but found nothing useful.  It looks like your web searching was much more successful than mine.  (By the way, I wouldn't know the difference between a github and a baloney sandwich.)  Anyway, it looks like the github link will enable me to e-mail johnwbyrd.  Thanks for your trouble.  Your a good friend Peter. I owe you a favor.